# IllegalArgumenException on click on every p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have javaee app running on JBossEAP 6.4. When I migrated to JbossEAP 7.2 I got `IllegalArgumenException` on click on every `p:commandButton`.

I use Primefaces 5.3, tried with higher versions but same thing happens. I also checked if I have some tags which are not closed but everything is clean.

```
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) end: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: end
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:265)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:508)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:558)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.processDecodes(UIRepeat.java:862)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.processDecodesOfFacetsAndChilds(ComponentUtils.java:251)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.processDecodes(UITabPanel.java:1032)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog.processDecodes(Dialog.java:396)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1032)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:79)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at com.myapp.service.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:51)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at com.myapp.util.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:35)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anybody know what happens and what is a reason for exception with `end` message?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and especially the [mcve] part and  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question... a lot

Comment: It basically says that the `end` attribute of an `<ui:repeat>` component has an illegal value. A normal [mcve] would be helpful for us to point out the problem in the code.

Comment: It was few included `.xhtml` files and one of them had `ui:repeat` component. Attribute `offset` caused exception. Thanks..

Comment: @FooGood If you solved the cause of the issue, please write an answer to this question containing the solution + accept the answer. It will help other users to know that this question has been answered, which is not apparent when the answer is written only "between lines" in comments. Thank you.